# Calculate the precision@k in Classify

Tags: dataset, machine-learning

I am interested to measure a precision@k. The  `Classify` function provides a build in an option for that or an elegant approach to calculate this without the need to implement the definition of precision@k?
The definition of precision@k  is

> precision@k = (# of recommended items @k that are relevant) / (# of
>   recommended items @k)

Comment: Can you give a MWE with the intended output. What is unclear to me "precison@k" is what: PPV_k? or something else?

Comment: I'll try later, right now I'm just with a mobile phone.
I did not really understand what is PPv_k that you use.